# Minimize Safari on iPad when installing an IPA in iOS 8

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari, ipa

I use adhoc deployment and supply a url to install an IPA file on the iPad. In iOS 7 (and previously) Safari would auto minimize and the user could see the app installing.  Now in iOS 8, Safari remains open and this appears to the user that nothing is happening.

Javascript / HTML techniques that I have explored will not work to close safari. 
Such as window.top.close();

Comment: I also have this question.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet.